# Threejs MeshStandardMaterial is rendered black

Tags: javascript, debugging, three.js, rendering, blender

Below is how the model should render
[image: blender preview]
However this is how threejs Rev 144 is rendering it
[image: threejs preview]
below is the material logged in the console
[image: material console log]

I've tried altering the metalness and roughness of the material, but it is a hack which makes the material dull
[image: hack and not a fix]

I've tried to add more spot lights, and tried changing the environmental map, but to no avail
[image: more lights fix]

I've tried the model on Don McCurdy's GLTF Viewer
[image: more tests don's gltf viewer]

I've tried to change the material of the wristband to the material of the clasp. Well, it gives better results, but not enough
[image: change material]

I have even tried the two narrow wristband material which are rendering correctly. But the material renders black on the large wristband.

Comment: It looks like the clasp on the back is rendering as expected. Maybe you could compare all the material properties between the clasp mesh and the wristband mesh. I'm thinking it's probably sampling the wrong part of a texture. Sometimes I have to y-flip the texture with GLTF, or sometimes I have to modify texture wrapping if UVs are outside the `[0, 1]` range. But it's really hard to pinpoint the exact issue with just screenshots.

Comment: Metallic materials reflect their environment map, and aren't very responsive to ambient or point lights. You might try different environment maps here, and/or load the model in a few glTF viewers to see how much of the issue is lighting-dependent, vs. part of the model itself.

Comment: I've checked all the properties in blender they are the exact same, I forgot to mention. I'm using a GLTFLoader, the model is exported in .gltf format with scene.bin and textures separated @Marquizzo

Comment: I've tried your GLTF Viewer @DonMcCurdy and have edited the post, kindly inform me if you need any more information about the issue, big fan :3

Comment: If I remove the environmental map all the other metallic meshes are rendered black, however when I add an environmental map all the others reflects the map, but the black one, hope this helps

Comment: What happens if you assign the same material to the black mesh after it's loaded? `wristband.material = clasp.material`? The clasp does show correct reflections, so the wristband might be missing UVs perhaps?

Comment: If the problem is visible in the threejs-based viewer and in https://sandbox.babylonjs.com/, it seems like the material hasn't exported from Blender correctly. If you can share a `.blend` that'd be ideal. Otherwise a screenshot of the affected material's settings in Blender. There is also a Blender-specific stack exchange: https://blender.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @DonMcCurdy I can share you the file in a Direct Message and not via a public link, but I honestly don't know the mean that suites you to share the .blend file